# Are Primitive Dirichlet Characters linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, arithmetic

For a positive integer $N$, let 
$$S_N=\{ \chi~\mid~ \chi \text{ is primitive Dirichlet characters modulo }F,\text{ where } F\mid N  \}.$$

I want to check the Linear independence on $S_N$. More preciesly:
Let $s\in \mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd(s,N)=1$. If

$$
\sum_{\chi\in S_N} c_\chi \chi(s)=0\qquad (c_\chi\in \mathbb{C}),
$$
then prove (or disprove) that the scalars $c_\chi$ are all zero.

Thanks

Comment: Essentially by the orthogonality relations for such characters it must be that each coefficient is $0$ (inner product the above relation by each character in turn and all terms disappear except one each time, allowing you to conclude that the coeff is $0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=(\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z)^\times$ and $R=L^2(G, \mathbb C)$ the Hilbert space of functions $G \to \mathbb C$, with inner product $\left<g, h\right> = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} f(g) \overline{h(g)}$. We can view $\widehat G = \hom(G, \mathbb C^\times)$ as a subset of $R$. It is elementary to check that the elements of $\widehat{G}$ are pairwise orthogonal under this inner product: this boils down to the fact that $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) = 0$ if $\chi$ is nontrivial and $=1$ if $\chi$ is trivial. It follows that  $\widehat{G}$ a linearly independent subset of $R$.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. There is still something I do not understand. In my definition I run over all characters modulo $F$ where $F$ is a divisor of $N$. It is clear that $|S_N|=\phi(N)=|G|$. But if I am not sure if there is one to one corespondents between $\widehat G = \hom(G, \mathbb C^\times)$  and my $S_N$? Bests

Comment: You are welcome @user31009. Given a primitive character $(\mathbb Z/F\mathbb Z)^\times \to \mathbb C^\times$, we can pull it back via the reduction $(\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z)^\times \to (\mathbb Z/F\mathbb Z)^\times$, to get an element of $\widehat{G}$, i.e. a non-primitive character mod $N$. This gives a map $S_N \to \widehat{G}$, which is bijective (a good exercise).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, linear independence of characters means that for every $s \in \mathbb{N}$ with $(s, N) = 1$, if $\sum_{\chi \in S_N} c_\chi \chi(s) = 0$, then each $c_\chi = 0$ for $\chi \in S_N$. However the original question has "Let s∈N with gcd(s,N)=1. If...". I think we can not conclude each $c_\chi = 0$ in this case, unless there's something I'm missing?

Comment: That is, it may still be possible to find a specific $s$ with $(s, N) = 1$, such that at least one of the scalars are $\neq 0$ but the sum is $0$